# How do I post serialized data along with a jQuery.getScript() call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to request an external JS file while also posting serialized data in that same request?  I'd like to pass along some values to validate the request, but not have those values be a part of the request url.

On the backend I'll process the posted values and return the proper JS after validation, then continue with the injected JS functions as a callback of getScript.

I see no data option in the API:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Answer (score 2):

`$.getScript` is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "script",
  success: success
});
```

So I assume You can use the following code to do that

```
$.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: {data: serializedData},
      dataType: "script",
      success: success
    });
```